# просмотр индексов

Tags: linux, база-данных, search, sphinx, поисковые-системы

Здравствуйте, возникли проблемы с sphinx rt index, добавляю индексы с помощью sphinxql через mysql 9306 - порт, потом пробую поиск с териминала search, выдает ошибку что не существует файла .sph, но при этом через sphinxql все работает, так и должно быть? И как посмотреть существующие индексы?

Answer (score 0):

Все индексы

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
```